# Airflow does not load DAG

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG in airflow 2.2.3, and it has 3 tasks.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(dag_id='myDag',
     start_date=datetime(2023, 5, 15),
     schedule_interval="0 5 * * *",
     max_active_runs=1,
     catchup=False)
def my_dag():
    
    @task
    def load() -> List[dict]:
        ... # load some data from database

    @task
    def make_jobs(params: list) -> List[List[dict]]:
        ... # with params from database, make some list of jobs. One job is List[dict].

    @task
    def do_job(job: list) -> None:
        ... # do job

dag = my_dag()
```

And I'd like to run tasks with this flow, especially execute do_job in parallel.

```
load() --> make_jobs() --> job_1
                       |-> job_2
                       |-> job_3
                       |   ...
                       --> job_n
```

So, I configured my task flow like this,

```py
    param_list = load()
    job_list = make_jobs(param_list)

    for job in job_list:
        do_job(job)
```

..but this DAG does not show in Airflow UI. I doubt I made something wrong when making the task flow.

Even when I run the command `python my_dag_file.py` it does not end.

If I convert `my_dag` to just python function(not a DAG) and run, it operates well as I intended.

Also, if I remove `for job in job_list: do_job(job)`, it is compiled at least.

I can't find something wrong in taskflow code... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you reload `scheduler`? are you sure that you have correct `$AIRFLOW_HOME` + `airflow.cfg` config(see `dags_folder` path)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar sorry for late reply, I checked configurations and already tried reload everything. My airflow version is under 2.3 and I read this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71874194/use-list-output-from-a-pythonoperator-to-iterate-another-operator-in-airflow2
since what I want to do is to generate tasks dynamically, it's not recommended in my airflow version...